# unit testing the session variables

Tags: scala, lift

I am extremely new in scala and lift. I have to build a simple application in which a user logs in with specific username and password. Later I have to store these values in a session variable. The value being stored in the session variable is a complete user object which is being retrieved after the user gets log in. The session variable is stored in a separate file. This file contains all the session related information including persisting user object, testing if the user is logged in and to remove the session. If I want to unit test this class, how can I do that???

Answer (score 1):

The wiki has two useful links about testing

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Unit_Testing_Snippets_With_A_Logged_In_User

And

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mocking_HTTP_Requests